# Specific geocoding error when using componentRestrictions

Tags: google-geocoding-api

When I try using componentRestrictions while geocoding:

```
geocoder.geocode({
  address: address,
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'AU',
  },
}
```

for:

`address = 'Sydney 2000'` (case sensitive)
I get:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

whereas, `address = 'sydney 2000'` 
gives me the normal results object for Sydney

(Also works for basically every other Australian capital city in the format 'Melbourne 3000')

Whereas if I use regions:

```
geocoder.geocode({
  address: address,
  region: 'AU'
}
```

using `address = 'Sydney 2000'` (case sensitive) again gives me normal results object for Sydney

I haven't yet seen this fail for anything other than `Sydney 2000`.  So while I have options to work around this on my end, I'm also confused why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue that you are experiencing is a known issue reported in Google issue tracker

[4-digit postal codes are hard to geocode (AT, AU, BE, CH, DK, NZ, SI)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75985322)

According to engineers at Google

> We are investigating a systemic issue that appears to make postal codes with 4 digits particularly difficult to find in the Geocoding API.
>
> For best result, the recommended request format is to use Component Filtering and Region Biasing towards the desired country:
>
> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?skip_auth&components=postal_code:2725|country:AU&region=AU`
>
> In Australia in particular, if feasible in your implementation, adding the administrative_area: filter helps with most postal codes in the 2000-2020 range.
>   (taking into account that postal codes 2001-2005 and 2012-2014 are not in Google Maps at all)
>
> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&components=country:AU|administrative_area:NSW|postal_code:2006`
>
> In other countries, wherever possible adding the locality filter would also help, as noted in #10.
>
> We will keep you posted here.

I would suggest reading all bug's messages and starring the bug in order to subscribe to further notifications from Google.